# Error after upgrading and downgrading: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on an app that uses some older dependencies and deprecated methods which I realized after upgrading to latest Flutter version.

So until i correct all of these, i downgraded back to v2.2.3 to be able to keep working on my app.

But now when i try to run i get some error that i didnt have before.

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/tooltip.dart:158:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/tooltip.dart:166:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/tooltip.dart:188:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/tooltip.dart:202:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/tooltip.dart:361:31: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/ballon_transition.dart:150:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/balloon.dart:56:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/balloon_positioner.dart:134:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/obfuscate_tooltip_item.dart:34:29: Error: Method 'addObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/obfuscate_tooltip_item.dart:43:29: Error: Method 'addPostFrameCallback' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/simple_tooltip-1.2.0/lib/src/obfuscate_tooltip_item.dart:59:29: Error: Method 'removeObserver' cannot be called on 'WidgetsBinding?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'WidgetsBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart' ('/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart').
Try calling using ?. instead.
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/carousel_slider-4.1.1/lib/carousel_slider.dart:268:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'padEnds'.
      padEnds: widget.options.padEnds,
      ^^^^^^^
/C:/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/page_view.dart:664:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  PageView.builder({
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried changing the location and removing of "?" as suggested in other threads but it only mad it worst.

Any idea of how i could solve this issue?

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app. Btw  i am curious to why you’ve downgraded the version, you may find other alterntive package,good one

Comment: I downgraded because i wasnt able to make it run after upgrading. So I reverted to the last know configuration that worked, but its not working anymore... So i'm trying to solve the issues in this config as i know it is supposed to work. And i'll work on upgrading once i managed to get it working again

Answer (score 0):

You should try the opposite. Replace

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()
```

with

```
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback()
```

As the error message tells you, `instance` might be null, so you need to safeguard it via `?`

Edit: If these calls come from external dependencies, you might have no other choice than to downgrade or change these dependencies.

Comment: I tried
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback()
WidgetsBinding?.instance.addPostFrameCallback()
WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback()
WidgetsBinding?.instance?.addPostFrameCallback()
But none have worked so far

Comment: That is interesting. Have you received the same error message for all of them? A problem could be that the changes in external packages are not saved and overriden by the next "flutter pub get" or "flutter run"? That would be my best bet

Comment: if it comes from a dependency, how to know which one it is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually got it to work. Not exactly sure why, but here's what I did.

- I created a new project from the Git repo (still had the same errors)
- Upgraded Flutter and dependencies (got lots of deprecation errors)
- Downgraded back to 2.2.3 and re-pulled the repo version of the code > now it works

The original project is still having the same issue thought. I have no idea why one works and not the other. They are basically running the same piece of code.